# Why is there different behavior with short-hand assignment and NaN?

Tags: python, numpy

I see this in python 2.7.3, with both pylab and numpy.  Why is this:

```
>>> x = pylab.arange(5)
>>> x = x + pylab.nan
>>> print x
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

different than this:

```
>>> x = pylab.arange(5)
>>> x += pylab.nan
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
>>> print x
[-9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808]
```

?

Comment: removed matplotlib tag because `pylab.arange` and `plab.nan` are really from `numpy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `arange(5)` returns an array of integers, but `nan` is a float value.  When you ise regular assignment, this is okay, because `x + nan` transparently converts `x` to float to do the addition and returns a float result.  But with `+=`, it tries to put this float result back into the original `x`, which is an int array.  This fails, because the int array can't accept float data.

Using `+=` with numpy arrays updates the array in place, and this won't work if the result of your computation is of a different datatype than the original.